# Window value is undefined - Electron js

Tags: node.js, electron

I am creating an electron app and I am trying to find ways to split my code into different modules for maintainability. I have my main.js file and I also have another file I created for the manipulation of windows (windowManipulation.js). This file has all the variables and functions necessary to create windows, and that part is working.

```
let window 1;
let window 2;

module.exports.createWindow1 = () => {
 window1 = new BrowserWindow({...})
}
...
```

and in main.js I have:

```
const windowManipulation = require("./windowManipulation.js");
...
```

I am able to create windows just fine; however, after the windows are created I can't use Javascript to close them because the value of the window variable is "undefined". I am thinking this is happening because the variable names are in the windowManipulation.js file and not in the main.js file, which means that the windows are created just fine, but then I lose all reference to them.

What is the best way to solve this? I could move all of the code in my windowManipulation.js file to the main.js file, but that would defeat the purpose of creating modules to make the code more maintainable. How do you handle windows in your ElectronJS apps so you can still have some modularity?

Comment: are the spaces between window and 1/2 accidental? when you say the window variable is undefined, are you talking about the window1 variable? how are you trying to close the window

Comment: Yes, that was my mistake typing it here. Sorry. I actually refer to any of the windows. I just used window1 and window2 as examples. I am trying to close the window from windowManipulation.js  for instance, module.exports.closeWindow1 = () => { window1.close()} , but it doesn't execute it because it says that window1 is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I decided to solve it. I put my window definitions in my main.js file and then create a function in that file as well that calls the function to create window in the windowManipulation file. This file returns the actual window.

main.js

```
...
const openWindow = require("./pathToFile")

let window1;
...
module.exports.createWindow1 = () => {
     window1 = openWindow.openWindow1();
}
```

windowManipulation.js

```
...
module.exports.openWindow1 = () => {
     let window1 = new BrowserWindow({
          ...
     })

     return(window1)
}
...
```

Now, if I want to manipulate window1, I can do it easily from my main.js.

I hope this helps someone.